# Error: [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected. You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-getx

There is no heavy widget, that why I am facing this issue:

Code:

```
 Obx(()=>InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            controller.login();
          },
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: 50,
            width: 150,
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
            child: Text('Login Here'),
          ),
        ),
     ),
```

I just want to call this function properly, instead it gives me error of *improper use of GetX*

Answer (score 0):

the `Getx` has `Obx` widget in order that it triggeres updates if that widget uses some observable `Rx`, if you didn't use any of it then this error is thrown since it is a waste of resources.

you will need either to start using an actual observable `Rx<T>` inside of it if you need it. otherwise if you don't want to update that widget then you don't need to wrap it with `Obx`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Obx(()=>InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            controller.login();
          },
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: 50,
            width: 150,
            // If you are using an Obx-wrapped widget, you need a variable created with <Rx> that affects the widget's state. You do not need to use the Obx widget for the controller value accessed within the functions.
            color: controller.someRxBoolValue ? Colors.red : Colors.greenAccent,
            child: Text('Login Here'),
          ),
        ),
     ),
```